# How to switch route namespace in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following router:

```
scope ':name' do                              # Category :name
  get :animators, controller: 'categories'
  get :creators, controller: 'categories'

  resources :items, only: [:show]
end
```

it generates the following URLs:

```
http://localhost:3000/birthday/ # index page
http://localhost:3000/birthday/item/123 # resource show page
```

However what I would like to do is make my second URL look like this

```
http://localhost:3000/birthday/animator/123 # resource show page
```

On my Item model `Animator` is a `:type`

If I do it with inner scope

```
scope ':type' do
  resources :items, only: [:show]
end
```

I will get

```
http://localhost:3000/birthday/animator/item/123
```

But I would like to get rid of item, plus it makes me indicate an additional parameter when using `link_to` in the view, which is not good.

Comment: `http://localhost:3000/birthday/`; it won't work. Because you have only mentioned `show` method, not the `index` one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added

```
get ':type/:slug', to: 'items#show', as: :item
```

to the scope block. It doesn't look pretty IMO, but I will try to fix that eventually.

Comment: Don't post it as answer over here, either post it as comment or edit your question.

Comment: And if you think that this is the answer, then accept it. Yes, you can accept your own answer. It will give +2 rep.

Comment: you should also mention that I can accept my own answers in two days only

Comment: I'm glad you already know! I didn't have in mind at that time this thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
scope ':name' do                                                              
  get :animators, controller: 'categories'                                    
  get :creators, controller: 'categories'                                     

  resources :items, only: [:show]                                             
  get '/animator/:id' => 'animator#show'                                                                                                 
end
```

`resources :items, only: [:show]` will only catch routes like `/birthday/items/1`, `/birthday/items/2` etc. While `get '/animator/:id' => 'animator#show` will be able to catch the routes like you have mentioned in your question:

```
http://localhost:3000/birthday/animator/123
```